# API Gateway Custom Domain ERROR - Unable to create CloudFront distribution for new domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, serverless

I setup Serverless NodeJS Rest API. Using AWS API Gateway and lambda function. All things are working as expected. However when I tried to create API Gateway Custom Domains (with the below details):

- Region: Bahrain
- Protocol: HTTP
- Domain Name: xxxxxx-dev.xxxxxxxx.com (masked with x for confidentiality)
- Security Policy: TLS 1.2
- Edged Optimized: true
- ACM Certificate Applied: ACM Cert from Region US East (N. Virginia)

But when I tried to save it, I received and error `Unable to create CloudFront distribution for new domain name. Ensure that the domain name is long enough to be valid and try again`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: can you try with shorter name like ? api.dev.xxxx.com something like this.

Comment: I can't use api.dev due to SSL issue but I will try api-dev.xxxx.com

Comment: try that domain.

Comment: the same error; I also tried ydev. xxxxxxxx.com but no luck.

Comment: can show me screenshot of your setting which you trying

Comment: Screenshot Link: https://imgur.com/4osCZVg

Comment: when i am trying not able to reproduce same error which you getting can you tell me exact domain which you trying and certificate ?

Comment: I think it's in the region issue? You tried in Bahrain as well?

Comment: We use us-east region. It not region specific issue

Comment: I think it's a region issue; I created the same custom domain from eu-west-1 and it worked. 

I also noticed the below differences between both regions when creating custom domain. 

eu-west-1: https://imgur.com/7D6oo6W
me-south-1: https://imgur.com/VYMhf2K

Comment: is this solved your issue or still there ?

Comment: I managed to solved the issue within the eu-west-1 region. However there was an internal issue that came up effect of that changing of region. But still it's not clear why in Bahrain region custom domain with the same config has that above error.